# Procedimiento almacenado se "salta" la transaccion SQL?

Tags: java, sql

tengo unos cuantos procedimientos almacenados en mi base de datos SQL. Lo que me ocurre es que estoy leyendo datos de un XML, y si mientras la grabación ocurre algún fallo con la BD, o con el fichero que estoy leyendo (salta una excepción de cualquier tipo), los datos no se graban en la BD y se descarta ese fichero. Mi problema está en que todo funciona correctamente menos un trozo del código que, aun habiendo fallos, escribe en la BD y no entiendo cómo, si la transacción (supuestamente) no lo permite.
Os dejo código para verlo más detalladamente:

```
private void writeNewIdsExpediente(Entry entry, int ids){
        Connection conn = conectarMySQL();
        
        CallableStatement sentencia = null;
        
        try {
            // INICIAMOS LA TRANSACCION
            // En caso de haber algun fallo con la base de datos, esta entry se descartará
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            
            sentencia = (CallableStatement) conn.prepareCall("{call newExpediente_Ids(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)}");
            
            sentencia.setInt("ids", ids);
            sentencia.setInt("expediente", Integer.parseInt(entry.getId()));
            sentencia.setString("summary", entry.getSummary());
            sentencia.setTimestamp("updated", entry.getUpdated());
            sentencia.setString("estado", entry.getContractFolderStatus().getContractFolderStatusCode());
            
            sentencia.execute();
            
            writeLugarDeEjecucion(entry);
            writeProcesoDeLicitacion(entry);
            writeEntidadAdjudicadora(entry);
            
            // FINALIZAMOS LA TRANSACCION
            conn.commit();
        } catch (SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            // Cerramos las conexiones
            try {
                if (sentencia != null) sentencia.close();
                if (conn != null) conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Como se puede observar, tras setear las variables del procedimiento almacenado, hago el execute, pero este no debería hacerse efectiva hasta no llegar al commit, por lo tanto no se debería grabar. Los procedimientos NO tienen una transacción dentro en el SQL, la única transacción que existe es esta que se ve en el código. Entonces, mi pregunta es, ¿cómo es posible que se salte el commit y grabe, si los tres métodos posteriores al execute también son de grabación, pero no lo hacen?

En un ejemplo probé a que el error estuviera en el método *writeEntidadAdjudicadora(entry)* y, como os digo, no se graba NADA excepto lo que grabe el procedimiento almacenado que muestro en el código.

Os dejo también la definición de este procedimiento:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `newExpediente_Ids`(
    IN ids INT,
    IN expediente INT,
    IN summary VARCHAR(400),
    IN updated TIMESTAMP,
    IN estado VARCHAR(45))
BEGIN
        INSERT INTO tbl_ids_expedientes (ids, expediente, summary, updated, estado)
        VALUES (ids, expediente, summary, updated, estado);
END
```

Comment: No coloca esto como respuesta porque nunca he encontrado un documento técnico de como  respaldarlo, pero hasta donde yo entiendo la transacción del `Procedimiento Almacenado` es independiente de la transacción de la conexión en en java, así que no es posible aplicar un commit o rollback a lo que se ejecuta en un procedimiento almacenado desde el Código Java.

Comment: Si el procedimiento almacenado es transaccional pero **NO** hace commit, *en teoría* debería aplicarse cuando haces el commit de la transacción en la que se ha llamado

Comment: Si escribe o no antes del commit, depende de cada motor de base de datos. Lo que yo veo incorrecto en tu código, es que nunca haces `rollback` de la transacción.  Si otras transacciones pueden _ver_ lo que escribió esta transacción depende del nivel de aislamiento de dichas transacciones.

Comment: Efectivamente lo que me faltaba era el rollback en el catch